# Проход по пикселям изображения, С#

Tags: c#

Как вычислять padding при использовании прямого доступа к пикселям изображения? Код ниже должен менять все пиксели на белые, но появляется System.AccessViolationException

```
   struct Pixel 
        {
            public byte Blue;
            public byte Green;
            public byte Red;
        }

public void startHandle()
        {
            Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(Path);
            var picBits = pic.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pic.PixelFormat);
            unsafe
            {          
               //получение указателя на первый пиксель изображения
               Pixel* px = (Pixel*)((byte*)picBits.Scan0);
               int padding = picBits.Stride - (pic.Width * sizeof(Pixel));
               for (int j = 0; j < pic.Height - 1; j++)
               {
                    for (int k = 0; k < pic.Width - 1; k++)
                    {
                        px->Blue = 255;
                        px->Green = 255;
                        px->Red = 255;
                        px += sizeof(Pixel);
                    }
                    px += padding;
               }
            }
            pic.UnlockBits(picBits);               
        }
```

Comment: Вы не проверяете формат изображения. Ничего не гарантирует, что в битмапе реально будет по три байта на пиксель.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В предположении, что ваш формат действительно 24 бита на пиксель, вы должны делать как-то так:

```
// using потому, что нужно освободить ресурс
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(path))
{
    // проверим формат. если он не такой, как ожидалось, наш код не имеет право его трогать
    if (bmp.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
        throw new ArgumentException("Мой код считает, что в картинке 3 байта на пиксель");
    const int bytesPerPixel = 3;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    BitmapData bits = null;
    try
    {
        bits = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
        unsafe
        {
            // указатель на Pixel не имеет смысла, лэйаут структур
            // в C# не определён
            // используем указатель на байт
            byte* start = (byte*)bits.Scan0;
            // цикл должен быть до H
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                // указатель на начало строки
                // поскольку Stride в байтах, мы вычисляем верно
                // а вот арифметика с Pixel* была бы здесь неверна
                byte* row = start + y * bits.Stride;
                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                {
                    // указатель на текущий пиксель
                    // опять-таки, арифметика с Pixel* была бы неверна
                    byte* pixel = row + x * bytesPerPixel;
                    pixel[0] = 255;
                    pixel[1] = 255;
                    pixel[2] = 255;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (bits != null)
            bmp.UnlockBits(bits);
    }
    // тут можно что-то сделать с картинкой
}
```